# how to load cell selection into parent uitableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have found an example that I am trying to wrap my head around, I have a subview thats loading values from my online resource into the section of uitableview cells.. everything is working sweet however now I want to capture the cell selection and pass that data back to the parent view cell that was selected. I think this example is what i need to get it working but I am struggling to understand what some of the variables are for in the example and am hoping someone can help me understand it abit better.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // do usual stuff here including getting the cell

    // determine the data from the IndexPath.row

    if (data == self.checkedData)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // determine the selected data from the IndexPath.row

    if (data != self.checkedData) {
       self.checkedData = data;
    }

    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

my main concerns are with **data** and **self.checkedData** is data the data coming back from the array of values that have been parsed? and what is checkedData? basically I want to have those check marks at the end of the cell when selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong considering there is no much context with that few lines of code but I'll give it a try.

First of all, it looks like you can have only one cell checked at a time.

`Data` seems to be the current cell and `checkedData` a way to keep track of which cell will get the checkmark.

Whenever a cell is selected it's marked:

```
if (data != self.checkedData) {
   self.checkedData = data;
}
```

And the controller asks the `TableView` to redraw (i.e. reload) itself again:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

When that action is fired-up, the delegate calls `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` (amongst other methods) and if you are the selected cell you get a checkmark:

```
if (data == self.checkedData)
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

Otherwise, you don't:

```
else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Comment: what is self.checkedData and how do I create my own one?

Comment: ahh its of tyep indexpath **@property(nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath *checkedData;**

Comment: if `checkedData` is an `NSIndexPath` then my answer is in the right track.

Comment: I would think `data` is the same as `indexPath`. Though I would change `data == checkedData` for `[data isEqual:checkedData]`.